# How to float/align images left and center text right (and vice versa)

Tags: css-float, liquid-layout

I'm struggling with some code where I'm trying to align/float an image to one side of a column row and float/center text to the opposite side.  What is happening is the image doesn't float all the way to the right; nor does the text align correctly when it is centered on the right.

It seems I can't attach an image.  You can view the image by navigating to my website "yukionna.com" and adding the name of the image to the url: css_problem_01.jpg

Here is my code:

CSS:

```css
.tn-container {
  height: 100px;
  background: #fff;
}
.tn-span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;  
} 
.tn-left img {
  float:left;
  width:110px;
  height:90px;
  margin:5px;
  text-align:right;
}
.tn-right img {
  float:right;
  width:110px;
  height:90px;
  margin:5px;
  text-align:left;
}
```

HTML:

```html
<!-- row 1  -->     
<div class="tn-container tn-left">
    <div class="tn-span">
        <img src="..." alt="">
        Row 1 text
    </div>
</div>

<!-- row 2  --> 
<div class="tn-container tn-right">
    <div class="tn-span">
        <img src="..." alt="">
        Row 2 text
    </div>
</div>

<!-- row 3  --> 
<div class="tn-container tn-left">
    <div class="tn-span">
        <img src="..." alt="">
        Row 3 text
    </div>
</div>

<!-- row 4  --> 
<div class="tn-container tn-right">
    <div class="tn-span">
        <img src="..." alt="">
        Row 4 text
    </div>
</div
```

Comment: Here's a [jsfiddle of the provided code](http://jsfiddle.net/pjmorse/4FyFW/) to help those who want to see it as it's run.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `width: 100%` to the `.tn-span` style. That should ask the span to occupy the full available width (and thus "properly" right-align your images). See [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/pjmorse/wtQjw/).